# Changing the Stacking Configuration on four Dell M6220 blade switches

Tags: dell, powerconnect, stacking

My main production environment is in a Dell M1000e blade chassis with M6220 switches in Fabrics B and C.  Fabric B is dedicated to vMotion traffic, and Fabric C is dedicated to iSCSi traffic and connected directly to our SAN.  None of the switches in either Fabric are connected to the rest of the network, so I am unable to monitor them, and I can only manage the configs through the Dell Chassis Management Controller.

When our consultants set this up two years ago, they configured stacking as follows:
C1=C2
B1=B2

I'd like to change the stacking configuration so it is looped in the following way:
B1=C1=C2=B2

If I make this change and merge the two stacks, will it change the configs on the switches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done, see the page 15 of the Dell white paper on the subject here:
http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pwcnt/en/pwcnt_stacking_switches.pdf

Specifically it says:

> Merging Two Operational Stacks
>
> The recommended procedure for merging two operational stacks is as
>   follows:
>
> 1. Always power off all units in one stack before connecting to another stack.
> 2. Add the units as a group by unplugging one stacking cable in the operational stack and physically connecting all unpowered units.
> 3. Completely cable the stacking connections, making sure the redundant link is also in place.
>
> Two operational stacks can also be merged by reconnecting stack cables
>   without powering down units in either stack. Connecting a powered up
>   standalone unit to an existing stack leads to same behavior as when
>   merging two operational stacks. In such cases, Manager reelection is
>   done and the Manager with the higher MAC address wins the election.
>   The losing stack manager resets itself and all its member units. After
>   the reset, all the losing stack members join the winning stack to form
>   a single stack. The winning stack remains functional through the merge
>   process. If the stack merge is performed in this way, then it is
>   strongly recommended that the user set the admin management preference
>   of the desired winner stack manager to a higher value than the stack
>   manager that should lose the election.

Also, in your above proposed cabling you are not completing a loop with your stacking cables. You should always aim to do this, even though it is not a requirement. See page 7 of the Dell m6220 stacking use case:
http://i.dell.com/sites/content/business/solutions/whitepapers/zh/Documents/powerconnect-m6220-switch_cn.pdf

> Cabling:
>
> M6220 switches should be stacked together by connecting a
>   stacking cable from stack port xg2 of one switch to stack port xg1 of
>   the next sw itch. The stacking cable is included with the stacking
>   module. Stack port xg2 of the fi nal switch in the stack should be
>   connected to stack port xg1 of the first switch, completing the stack
>   loop. A loop topology is not strictly required for a stack but it is
>   recommended, as it is the most robust stacking topology and has seen
>   the most time in production use.

Answer (score 4):

The main part about this is the switch IDs for the devices. If you have two switch stacks which BOTH have units 1 and 2 your interfaces are named 1/g1, 1/g2, 2/g1 etc. When they are combined into one stack the configuration of at least two will change.

So:

1. Do backups of the configuration
2. Get a service window :-)
3. Shutdown two units, and join them to the stack
4. Paste the configuration for the "new units" 3/g1-24, and 4/g1-24 etc.

TL;DR interface numbers follow switch id and switches cannot automatically merge two stack configs